# Iterating over a large string and checking membership of substrings in a dictionary performance

Tags: python, string, performance

I am currently implementing Huffman coding in python and I've finished it but I want to make it more efficient.

This is the method I use to get the content of the original file

```
def getDecodedFile(self, text, codes):
        code = ""
        origin = []        
        for ch in text:
            code += ch
            if code in codes:
                origin.append(codes[code])
                code = ""
        bCodes = bytes(origin)
        return bCodes
```

`text` Is the large string and `codes` is a dictionary of Huffman codes (Key is a string of the code and value is an int between 0 and 255)

I've trying using `''.join(somelist)` instead of `code += ch` but the result was way slower. Currently this method takes 3 seconds to execute with `len(text) = 13972363` and the shortest code length is `6`

Example of data:

`text = "0100101110111"`

`codes = {'0': 65, '100': 66, '101': 67, '110': 68, '111': 69}`

That would result in `origin = [65,66,67,68,69]`

I would appreciate any suggestion to make my code efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, one improvement you can do is when you do this:

```
code += ch
if code in codes:
    origin.append(codes[code])
code = ""
```

Specifically, you check `if code in codes:` each time you modify `code`. For example, for a code of length *k*, you will end up performing a O(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + *k*) = O(0.5 * *k* * *k*+1) = O(*k*²) operation here. Instead, you should preprocess `codes` by building a Huffman Tree and doing a single O(*k*) traversal down the tree to decode your code (start at the root, and read a single 1 or 0 at a time and go down the respective child edge; once you hit a letter, output it in the decoded message and move back to the root of your tree). Not only does this explicitly save on the time complexity of the check `if code in codes:`, but it also avoids rebuilding a string `code` each time you do `code += ch`.

Aside from this, I'm not sure if you can optimize further. I wonder if it would be faster to convert each individual decoded letter to a `byte` and append to the output list, as opposed to decoding the letters to a list and then converting the list via `bytes(origin)`?

Comment: what I did is I used the tree to decode the codes instead of using a dictionary and that saved about 0.5 seconds, but converting each letter to byte actually slowed it down so I kept my list. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, that's the fastest way you can implement Huffman decoding in terms of algorithm implementation. Any further optimizations are low-level things (e.g. storing the tree as an array to minimize memory-access slowdown, writing in a faster language, etc.)

Comment: Time went down to 0.6 seconds for the same file using pypy3 instead of the default interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest performance boost will come from using something like a trie to store your Huffman tree. this will let you descend one level at a time, which will remove the need for string concatenation or repeated checking for presence.